# Unable to connect to Apache website hosted on VPS

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, debian

I have set up a basic LAMP stack on a self managed VPS and now I would like to to preview the site by the IP assigned by our provider - before switching DNS over. Chrome reports the following error when trying to access the site.

I see the following in the logs:

```
[Mon May 28 14:06:07 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

when I try to access by the IP. The only other customisation was installing Nagios which seems to be fine - although I cannot access that by http"//MY IP/nagios either

Comment: Please provide the output of `apache2ctl -S`.

Comment: Please edit your question when providing additional information -- comments are not intended for that purpose.

Comment: What does the browser report when you try to access the site?

Comment: Is Apache actually running (`ps -eF | grep apache`)? Is there a firewall (`iptables -nvL`)? Can you connect to this IP address on a different port (e.g. SSH)?

Comment: apache running - ssh is fine

Comment: Your apache setup has issues, but the topic is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an entry to the hosts file on the client which you're testing from which maps the domain to the IP you want to test against. The hosts file is (usually) consulted before DNS, so this will override the IP configured in DNS. On *nix this file is `/etc/hosts` (I'm not sure offhand about other OSes.) I'm assuming that you've already configured Apache to respond for this domain.

```
1.2.3.4     example.com
```

(Remember to remove this when you actually switch DNS over so that you don't mask DNS issues.)

Comment: yeah - the clients ok - it is some configuration on the server I guess. I better re-phrase my question before I get down voted into oblivion - grumpy server admins? - we all have to start somewhere right!

Comment: Yup, please edit your question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else finds this useful - our dedicated server came with the firewall pre-configured - port 80 was blocked. I had to make alterations IPtables.

Answer (score -1):

You only need to change your host file. /etc/hosts

Comment: thanks - actually I may not have provided enough info - I know to change the /etc/hosts but I am getting the error because some server configuration - my question seems to be attracting down votes too!